# Spring Data Flow JDBC Sink JSON

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-dataflow

I've created a custom sink off of the JDBC Sink Starter. The input to the sink is JSON content, but when the sink receives the message I receive the following error in the logs:

```
 Property or field 'field' cannot be found on object of type 'byte[]'
```

I'm using the property `jdbc.columns` as follows:

`jdbc.columns=FIELD_COLUMN:field`

The processor feeding the sink is sending the message as:

```
String payload = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message);
                output.send(MessageBuilder
                        .withPayload(payload)
                        .setHeader("contentType", "application/json")
                        .build());
```

Comment: Which version of app starters you are using? This is known issue

Comment: I'm using `org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-jdbc:2.1.0.RELEASE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an improvement required to explicitly handle payloads of different kinds starting from the 2.0.x release of `jdbc` app-starters.

We are tracking that via [spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/jdbc#48](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/jdbc/issues/48). Feel free to share your thoughts/questions as comments.

We will review and resolve it soon. In the meantime, please try the workaround by setting the upstream content-type as `text/plain` for now.

Comment: Great, thanks! Your team has been incredibly helpful so far.

Comment: The problem is now resolved in `jdbc-sink`. Feel free to try out `maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:jdbc-sink-rabbit:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` when you get a chance. We can release it whenever, but it would be good if you could verify it on your side before the release.

Comment: What nexus repo was that pushed to?

Comment: Oh, it is available in the Spring Snapshot repository. Here: http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/jdbc-sink-kafka/2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT - likewise, the usual Docker Hub account include the SNAPSHOT tag of the same app as well.